# Mediawiki: Pages with & and + in Name not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I discovered a bug in my mediawiki.

When I try to open a page with a + or a & in the name, it end up in a "The Site can't be reached"-Error. In the logs i can see, that i get a high number of HTTP 301 Codes when reaching such a Page. It also translates the characters:

+ into %2B

& into %26

But is does seem like it's not getting translated back? I'm also not using any mod_rewrite Code, well atleast none that I know of.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL#URL_like_-_example.com.2FPage_title
This describes my Problem (under Troubleshooting), but / works fine. But as I mentiond, I don't use any URL rewriting.

I would appreciate some help, thanks :)

Edit: I've just tested some more characters that are legal for pagetitles, seems like = isn't working either.

It's translated from = into %3D

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: So my Mainpage is at https://techwiki.example.ch/index.php/Hauptseite and there is a Link to "Hardware & Software". when I click on this Link, the browser tries to load the page and fails with the URL https://techwiki.example.ch/index.php/Kategorie:Hardware_%26_Software. Apache logs the following error 20-30 times before the brwoser gives up:"GET /index.php/Kategorie:Hardware_&_Software HTTP/1.1" 301 1

So it seems like the translation between & -> %26 isn't working properly, but other specialchars like / or " are working..

Comment: Where does the 301 point to?